# Create a page that automatically redirects to latest post of a specific tag/category?

Tags: redirect

I'm looking to make a URL like for example:

```
http://localhost/latest-news
```

Where the page for `latest-news` will automatically redirect to the latest news article (article with `news` category tag).

I then will need to use the link /latest-news in a few different places (menu, and a slider on the front page).

Comment: Why would you like to do this? If you want to show the latest article, then [`create a template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template) which fetches the latest article and assign it to a page, which you can use in any menu or slider in the front page etc.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty, so I would set that new page to have a URL of /latest-news ? Then set a custom template for that page so that it wp_redirect()s to the actual news content page? // thus user clicks latest-news but it shows up as /news/2014/04/09/the-latest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to list the steps below which worked for me:

Step 1) In the **Admin Panel** create a Page called "Latest News" which will have the slug you want `latest-news`.

Step 2) In your **Theme Folder** create a blank file and save it as `page-latest-news.php`. Inside the file, add this:

```
<?php
    $recent = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => 1));
    $blogID = get_option('page_for_posts');

    if(!empty($recent))
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($recent[0]->ID) ,307);
    else
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($blogID), 307);
```

Step 3) Upload your `page-latest-news.php` file and test it out.

I decided to go with 307 redirects because of the Temporary status, which I imagine the latest post will change frequently. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Great, thanks! Got it working with:

<?php

    $latestpost = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
     'category' => 7,
        ) );

    wp_redirect(get_permalink($latestpost[0]->ID), 307);